# command prompt change word save type

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I am using microsoft office 2010. I want to know in windows application open the word document choose File -- Save As option click change save as type as .doc to .pdf. If same option to work in command prompt (i.e) command prompt change save as type is possible?

Answer (score 0):

go to this site:http://www.a-pdf.com/office-to-pdf/index.htm
and use this command:

```
OfficeToPDF "c​​:\help.doc" "c:\output\help.pdf"
```

check this link for more:
https://superuser.com/questions/393118/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-from-windows-command-line

Comment: I need open source because inbuild command line convert to any where without any tool to install